# How can I get values of variables awaiting model update in Gurobi python

Tags: python, gurobi, nonlinear-optimization

I develop a quadratic programming model using Gurobi python API.
In terms of objective formulation containing a function associated with decision variable, such as obj = f(x) + g(y), I need to get values of the decision variables for the functions f(), g(). This is why the input of functions f(), g() should be list or array type acceptable format to the functions while Gurobi model uses tupledict structure that does not fit for general calculation. How can I get values of variables awaiting model update as below?

```
: x[0] <br>
: <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>

---------------------- pseudo code ---------------------------

import gurobipy as gp<br>
from gurobipy import GRB

def func():

mdl = gp.Model()

x = mdl.addVars(100, lb=0, vtype=GRB.INTEGER)

for i in range(100):<br>
    _x[i] = x[i]      # TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Var'<br>
    _x[i] = x[i].X    # AttributeError: Index out of range for attribute 'X'

obj = func(_x)

mdl.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking for or intending to do. In general, you cannot access the `X` attribute of variables before optimizing the model because these are the solution values of those variables. You need to have at least one solution at hand to get those values.

When setting up the model, you can just use the variables that you created before to participate in any constraints.

Please also note that you cannot input a custom function into the objective. You need to define the function in terms of the Gurobi variables you added before.

You may want to check out Gurobi's modeling guides: https://www.gurobi.com/resource/modeling-basics/

EDIT:
The thread continued in [Gurobi's official forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4416886974609-How-can-I-get-values-of-variables-awaiting-model-update-in-Gurobi-python).